# ESXi Installer reboots before installing ESXi

Tags: vmware-esxi

I have a Rackable System, built in early-to-mid 2000's with the following specs:
System Board Model: Intel SE7501CW2
2x 64bit Intel Xeon processors
4GB RAM
4x 250GB SATA HDDs on a 3ware Storage RAID Controller
2x Gbit NICs

I downloaded the iso for EXSi Server, created a bootable USB with UNetbootin, and booted the server on the USB drive, where I'm presented with the option to boot to the ESXi Installer or the hard drive.

I have tried both letting the ESXi start automatically (in graphical mode), as well as trying to install in text mode (by hitting tab on the first screen, and only typing "text" at the prompt).

Either way, I wait for a few moments while the server loads mboot.c32 vmkboot.gz  --- vmkernel.gz --- sys.vgz --- cim.vgz --- ienviron.vgz
 --- install.vgz.

All of these seem to load just fine, saying "OK" beside each one as they are loaded, and then after install.vgz, the server immediately reboots. I don't even make it to [this screen](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/3-vmware-esxi-install-prompt.png).

I've reviewed the "ESX and vCenter Server Installation Guie ESX 4.1 PDF" guide provided by VMware, as well as [Intel's specs](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/se7501cw2/tps.pdf) for this board, and haven't come up with a solution yet. This is the first time I've ever attempted any kind of bare-metal virtualization installation.

Has anyone encountered similar symptoms, and/or does anyone have any suggestions for how I might get to the next step of the installation process?

If I had to guess, I would say that something on this machine is incompatible with ESXi, but I have no idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your hardware isn't on the [Compatibility List](http://www.vmware.com/resources/compatibility/search.php) then there's a very good chance it won't work - it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issues when installing on hardware that is not compatible with ESXi 4.  Have you confirmed that VT is on?  You could also try installing ESXi 3.5